# NullPointerException while creating mapping file using hibernate tools

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, hibernate-tools

I am using hibernate tools to create mapping file but once i select the class and when i go to next step i get this error in eclipse

> Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in:
>   "org.eclipse.jface".
>
> stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.ConfigurationActor.getService(ConfigurationActor.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.ConfigurationActor.createConfiguration(ConfigurationActor.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.ConfigurationActor.createConfigurations(ConfigurationActor.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewHibernateMappingFileWizard.createConfigurations(NewHibernateMappingFileWizard.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewHibernateMappingFileWizard.getPlaces2Gen(NewHibernateMappingFileWizard.java:330)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewHibernateMappingFileWizard.handlePageChanging(NewHibernateMappingFileWizard.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog$10.run(WizardDialog.java:1643)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.firePageChanging(WizardDialog.java:1640)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.doPageChanging(WizardDialog.java:956)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1246)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.NewWizardShortcutAction.run(NewWizardShortcutAction.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

> Session Data

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.7.0_72
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
```

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, Can anyone have the solution??? I am using Eclipse Luna, Java Version 8 and Wildfly 8.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this. If you reproduce this in recent release of JBoss Tools please open bug at https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBIDE so we can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue when using Luna and JBoss Tools 4.2. I guess it's a bug in JBoss Tools 4.2. So there are two solutions for this:

1. Using Eclipse Kepler and its corresponding JBoss Tools.
2. Using Luna and JBoss Tools 4.1.

Either will work.